# dplyr summarise logical condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr, summary

I have the following data frame

```
df <- data.frame(Gender = c(rep(c("M","F"),each=4)),
             DiffA=c(1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1),
             DiffB=c(1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1))
```

I would like to create 2 new variables which summarize for each gender i)the number of rows for which DiffA and DiffB are positive and ii) the number of rows for which DiffA and DiffB are negative in order to obtain:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Gender = c("M","F"),
             Diff_Pos=c(1,3),
             Diff_Neg=c(1,1))
```

I have failed to combine the summary function from dplyr n() which returns the count of rows and the required logical statement. Thanks in advance

Comment: `... sum(DiffA > 0 & DiffB > 0) ...`

Answer (score 3):

I would consider doing

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% filter(DiffA == DiffB) %>% count(Gender, DiffA) %>% spread(DiffA, n)

  Gender    -1     1
#   (fctr) (int) (int)
# 1      F     1     3
# 2      M     1     1
```

The analogous data.table code is

```
dcast(df[DiffA == DiffB, .N, by=.(Gender, DiffA)], Gender ~ DiffA)

#    Gender -1 1
# 1:      F  1 3
# 2:      M  1 1
```

If your real data goes beyond `-1` and `1`, wrap the relevant columns in `sign()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option

```
 with(subset(df, DiffA==DiffB), table(Gender, DiffA))
 #      DiffA
 #Gender -1 1
 #     F  1 3
 #     M  1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Diff_Pos = DiffA > 0 & DiffB > 0,
    Diff_Neg = DiffA < 0 & DiffB < 0) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Gender) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(
    Diff_Pos = sum(Diff_Pos),
    Diff_Neg = sum(Diff_Neg))
```